# WordPress post article on Laravel blade page

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-4

I tried to reach this site [Working laravel 4 and 5 and WordPress together](http://grossi.io/2014/working-with-laravel-4-and-wordpress-together/), however there is one more thing I utterly don't get on my blade page. I would like to post my articles from my blog on my Laravel page, working with "foreach" and standard WordPress syntax. Still I get an error. Here's my code.

*I follow this from the site.*

```
class CreicController extends BaseController {

  public function index() 
  {
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => 'posts',
      'post_per_page' => 4,
      'order' => DESC,
    ));

    $posts = $query->get_posts();

    return View::make('layouts.creic')->with('posts', $posts);
  }

}
```

and I would like to use foreach to my blade page then i get lost (i tried to copy and do something in php but no luck).

Here's my old PHP before Laravel

```
<!-- Start Articles -->
<?php
  $posts = get_posts('numberposts=4&order=desc');
  foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post );
?>
<artcile class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 article-section">
  <div class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(80,80, true) ); ?>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
      <time datetime="2015-2-23T01:30:08Z" title="February 23, 2015" class="timeago"></time>
    </div>
  </div>
</artcile>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<!-- End Articles -->
```

Comment: Assuming you have access to the a `posts` collection from your WP_Query. Just do a foreach with the `posts` collection.
Your "old PHP" will not work inside laravel because it uses the Wordpress API to retrieve the data. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Yes sir, my old PHP was running at my normal HTML/PHP codes, before i switch to Laravel. What I just need here is to hook and post articles from my WordPress over to my blade template page... I don't know how to properly code or call the function that I copied from the given tutorial where i will convert my old codes into Laravel codes. Sorry, I am new to Laravel...

Comment: if you return your posts as a collection. Then a simple foreach will do. Then you can cache the results and create an event which will fire whenever you create a new post :)